# EF6 Self Reference contains n items (good!) but contents are NULL (bad!)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, self-reference

I took over a project which is calling a method on a server (WCF).

Here is the method

```
public FooDto GetBarById(int BarId)
{
    using(var repo = new ReadRepo<Foo>(FooBarContainer.GetInstance<FooBarDbContext>()))
    {
        var result = repo.GetByIdInclude(BarId,
                k => k.SelfReferenceList
        );
        return Mapper.Map<FooDto>(result);
    }
}
```

The Foo.cs contains the following line:

```
public ICollection<Foo> SelfReferenceList { get; set; }
```

It's funny, that when I get a result, that collection contains 2 items, since I want to see 2 entries.

BUT: The content of both fields are NULL!

Is there ANYTHING that has to be changed at k.SelfReferenceList? I tried to add Select(x=>x.existingFieldName) but it led to an exception.

Comment: I am not sure how you think anyone without source code can answer this question? Should we guess what `GetByIdInclude` does or what it does with the passed in parameters? What about `Mapper`, is this a nuget package or a home grown something? Is it relevant to the question?

Comment: And the most important thing: how the mapper (I guess AutoMapper) was configured, is missing.